# How to test API requests and responses matches with swagger definition in C#

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, assertions

I know there is some utilities to test that API request and responses matches with swagger definition in Java or PHP languages (like[SwaggerAssertions](https://github.com/Maks3w/SwaggerAssertions)) but I need something similar in C# for using in .NET platform.

I have been searching for something similar to match my swagger definition but I didn´t find any utility. Do you know anything? Is there any library in C# that allows doing asserts with a JSON model as parameter?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've the OpenAPI/Swagger spec, you can use [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) (free, open-source) to generate C# API client, which comes with documentations and test cases. You can then update the test cases accordingly to test the API requests and responses.

Another way to generate C# API client is to use https://editor.swagger.io, then import your spec, and select C# under "Generate Client" in the top menu.

(https://edtior.swagger.io leverages generator.swagger.io to generate API clients, server stubs and documentations and generator.swagger.io is also powered by the open-source project Swagger Codegen)

Comment: Yes, I know how to generate Swagger spec for my API, but I want some utility, library or some way to validate mi Swagger spec with the unit test generated to test requests and responses so that way code, documentation and unit test are always syncronized.